# Where did all the people in the Quantum Realm come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania

Minor *Quantumania* spoilers ahead:

In *Ant Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, we find that Janet spent an unknown amount of time all alone in the Quantum Realm before Kang showed up with a broken MacGuffin that needed fixing.  After this point, they spent a really long time fruitlessly trying everything they could think of to fix it, all alone, just the two of them.

However, the rebels that Scott and Cassie meet say that Kang conquered their lands and built his empire on the ruins of their civilization. So one moment the Quantum Realm is barren and lifeless, inhabited only by bizarre beasts and two castaways from other worlds stranded there all alone together, and the next it's abruptly teeming with native civilizations just ripe for a Conqueror to conquer.

Where did all these people come from? And why did Janet and Kang apparently never notice them until after the fateful moment when they had their falling-out?

Comment: Clearly the quantum people didn't exist until we observed them.

Comment: Most of your post is hidden under spoiler markup/protection. Could you consider editing your post to provide more context outside of the spoiler-hidden text? I suggest using spoiler markup sparingly, and only for the most spoilery parts of your post. Relevant meta posts regarding spoiler protection: [\[1\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114923/162827) [\[2\]](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/1006) [\[3\]](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/1006).

Comment: Well, when a quantum mother and a quantum father love each other very much...

Comment: They needed to make complete movie in quantum realm, so some characters were needed. So they created them.

Answer (score 1):

##### They are native inhabitants of the Quantum Realm.

Janet Van Dyne and Hank Pym have described the Quantum Realm as a universe of its own.

> **Janet**: There are worlds here, worlds within worlds. […] It's a secret universe beneath ours.

> **Hank**: There are beings down here. Intelligent beings. I always theorized it was
> possible, but to be here, a subatomic universe. This changes everything
> we know about life, evolution, our place in the galaxy...

This is consistent with the comics. The MCU's Quantum Realm is based on the comics' [Microverse](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Microverse), which is also its own universe and home to the [Micronauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micronauts_(comics)) — native inhabitants of the Microverse.

> So one moment the Quantum Realm is barren and lifeless, inhabited only by bizarre beasts and two castaways from other worlds stranded there all alone together, and the next it's abruptly teeming with native civilizations just ripe for a Conqueror to conquer.

When Janet and Kang were stranded there, they may have been in a barren and lifeless location, but that does not mean that the entire Quantum Realm is barren and lifeless.

There are other civilizations living in other parts of the Quantum Realm, and Kang only began conquering them after Janet sabotaged his multiversal engine core. The rebels didn’t just pop up suddenly out of nowhere.

> And why did Janet and Kang apparently never notice them until after the fateful moment when they had their falling-out?

They were too preoccupied with fixing Kang’s ship / multiversal engine core to interact with the natives. Remember, both of them had a strong motivation to fix Kang’s ship so they could leave the Quantum Realm, for their own reasons. After their falling out, it became clear to both that Kang’s ship / multiversal engine core was not getting fixed, so Kang resorted to his usual strategy: conquering, and Janet joined the rebels and opposed him.

Comment: Honestly all we know is that they look human, they could actually have a different biology